# Удалить элементы словаря при пустых значениях

Tags: python

Как в словаре удалить пустые ключи?

```py
d = {'1': [], '4': [], '5': [1, 2, 5, 6]}
```

чтобы получить

```py
d = {'5': [1, 2, 5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict(filter(lambda x:x[1], d.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
res = {}

for key in d:
    if len(d[key]) >= 1:
        res[key] = d[key]
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `dictionary comprehension`:

```py
d = {'1': [], '4': [], '5': [1, 2, 5, 6]}
d = {key:value for (key, value) in d.items() if value}
```